# Could we use an equal-contribution tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have found 61 questions searching for "equal contribution". Since, I don't have the required reputation, maybe someone else wants to add this tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we already have "authorship" as a tag, it makes sense to make "equal-authors" a synonym for authorship ("co-authors" is also a synonym). I've entered this into the tag "dictionary."